# Probability Of 2 consecutive dice throw for 4 players

Tags: probability-theory

Consider a fair dice. 4 players are throwing the dice one after another. If some one gets 6 he will get extra chance to throw it again. So he will throw it twice and then the next player will get the chance.

Now someone want to calculate the probability of Player A getting 2 consecutive 6 before any other player throws.

If there is one player throwing the dice continuously then the chance of getting 2 consecutive 6 is 1/36. [out of 36 possible outcome (1,1) ,(1,2) ..(3,3),(3,4)....(6,5),(6,6) only one is favorable].

But if there are more than one player, while calculating the probability should I consider Player A's throws exclusive [and it remains 1/36] of others' throws or will it depend on others also.[Possible outcomes : (1,1,1,1),(1,1,1,2)  ........... (**3,4,5,[6,6],**) .......... ]
So here 4th player wins.

I am new to probability and regret if the question is too naive

Comment: Two consecutive $6$ when?  How many throws does A get?

Comment: The question seems incomplete.  The probability of player A getting 2 consecutive sixes within 5 throws of the dice? within 100 throws of the dice? within $10^{10^{100}}$ throws of the dice? Before some other player throws consecutive sixes?

Comment: Added clarity to the question

Comment: I am really having trouble reading your question.  Can you say exactly what your question is in a sentence or two and I can edit it into your post?

Comment: Whoever will throw 2 consecutive 6 is winner and the game stops there. What is the probability that player A win

Answer (score 3):

I should mention, my interpretation of the problem (which still might not be the correct one) is that this game is played by four players.  The person whose turn it is throws a six sided die.  If it comes up as a six, he gets a bonus turn and throws again.  If it is again a six he wins.  Else, it becomes the next person's turn, going counter-clockwise indefinitely until a winner is found (there will always be a winner eventually).

> An alternate interpretation with a much simpler solution is if each person gets only one chance to win and it is possible for all players to lose (after it is player D's turn and player D doesn't win, all players lose).  Consider a simple tree diagram for that.

This can be described using markov chains using 13 states, with states labeled $A$ for if it is player $A$'s first turn or player $A$'s turn immediately after one of player $D$'s turns, state labeled $A^+$ if it is player $A$'s extra turn after having rolled a six, and $A^{win}$ if player $A$ successfully rolled two sixes in a row.  Similarly labeled for other states.

Here is the transition diagram:

[image: Transition Diagram]

From this, we can get the transition matrix with the order $A^{w}, B^{w}, C^{w}, D^{w}, A,B,C,D,A^+,B^+,C^+,D^+, start$

$\begin{bmatrix} 
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{6} & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

This is in the form $A=\begin{bmatrix} I & S\\ 0 & R\end{bmatrix}$ which $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} A^n = \begin{bmatrix}I & S(I-R)^{-1}\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

---

After tedious calculations, you will get to the fundamental matrix $(I-R)^{-1}$ which tells you that the average number of turns (including bonus turns, not counting start) that the game will go for is (almost ironically) $42$.

And the probability that $A$ wins is approximately $26.07\%$

> specifically 279936/178991 * 1/6

The fundamental matrix was calculated and is displayed below if curious:

> [image]